# Reasons why Browser asks to Save file instead of updating page with JSON result

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

Does anybody have a list of reasons why a browser would ask to save a file of JSON data instead of using it to update the page according to functions already present?  I had this working for a while, but all of a sudden, I did something that caused that to not work anymore.  I am using asp.net MVC4.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As you see I have included the appropriate scripts.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"), OnSuccess = "binddata", OnFailure = "FailAlert" }, new { id = "searchByDemographics" }))
```

I use Ajax.BeginForm() as you can see.

Here is the function that I use to return the JSON result

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchByDemographic(SearchByDemographicModel SearchByDemo)
    {
        string UID = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();
        List<SelectListItem> retVal = dr.SearchByDemographic(SearchByDemo, UID);
        if ((retVal == null) || (retVal.Count < 1))
            return Json("Empty Record: No Patient Found", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            if(retVal[0].Text.Contains("Error")){
                return Json(new {success = false, nameError = "General Return Exception"}, DataRepository.searchPatientJSonStr(retVal), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else{
                return Json(DataRepository.searchPatientJSonStr(retVal), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }//return PartialView("_RetTable", Json(DataRepository.searchPatientJSonStr(retVal), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));            
    }
```

This keeps happening to me.  I am ignorant of the reasons why this could happen.  If I could figure out why this keeps happening I would be in a better position to fix it in the future.

From my knowledge, The browser is expecting JSON data, and somehow or the other, it is not getting it?
Also,  Here is JSON of test data being passed back...  If it is a little off forgive me, I tried to get a single result out of a list of 20...

```
"{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":1,\"rows\":[{\"id\":11248971,\"cell\":[\"CRAYON \",\" RED \",\" 1956-03-04 \",\" M \",\" 11248971 \",\" 840006723 \",\" 737452545\"]}]}
```

[image: I do load unobtrusive-ajax]

I still always just get a prompt to open the file.

[image: My Return Type]

Comment: You should use Firebug, Fiddler, etc. to make sure that the unobtrusive javascript file is actually loading.  This sounds like the request is not being made via Ajax and instead you are submitting the form in the regular fashion.  When the server returns the JSON it has a content-type where the browser is presenting you with a save file dialog.

Comment: I just updated my post... Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried different browsers other than ie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is only present in IE due to a configuration option named "Show friendly JSON errrors" which makes ie ask to save your json if it's smaller than a certain size ( i seem to remember 200 characters) instead of consuming it normally

A possible solution is to use

```
return Json(result, "text/html");
```

which will make IE behave correctly

Comment: I will give that a shot.  How did you come to learn of this behaviour?

Comment: It happened to me a couple of times when uploading a file to an mvc action with a plugin that expected a json response containing the status of the operation. It's a hard to debug problem because it happens only on ie and only when this option is set.

Comment: It would seem as though it still doesn't work.  I am ata  complete loss.  Text/Html simply opens an Html Page containing my JSON result.  Same with text/plain.  They both open new pages in the browser, one text and the other html.

Comment: I just got rid of the Ajax.BeginForm and use HTML.BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

```
              public JsonResult Index()
{
         Models.MyEntities Object = new Models.MyEntities();
        var vperson = Object.Person;
        return Json(vperson, "text/html", behavior:JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your proposed solution. It will help readers understand what you are trying to accomplish. Thank you.