# Accessing Object from Hidden field using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I try to access Hidden field from js, i get the name of the object and not the object itself.

In my razor (.cshtml) page i have the following

```
 @Html.Hidden("xyz", Model)
```

In js if i try to do

```
var cmodel = $('#xyz').val();    
alert(cmodel);
```

When I try to access cmodel, i get the string not the object

Comment: just `$('#xyz')` no need to use `.val()` when you need the element itself. use `.val()` when you need the value of the element

Comment: You cannot bind a complex model to a hidden input - look at the html you have generated

Comment: If you want the whole model as a javascript object, then use `var cmodel = @Html.raw(Json.Encode(Model))`

Comment: No need to use hidden helper, just project it as raw data: `var cmodel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought the same but if that is the case MS shouldn't allow us to store Object in Hidden field right?

Comment: The hidden helper accepts value-type properties, not model class object. The objects should be stored inside `ViewBag`, `TempData` or `Session` variables.

Comment: It has nothing to do with MS - its your browser (which has no knowledge of c# or you model). You could always serialize the model to a string and store it in a hidden input, but there is no point

Comment: @StephenMuecke while trying to do Json.Encode(Model), i get circular reference issue

Comment: Then pass a correct view model to the view (which does not contain circular references)

Comment: Try read this post for circular reference issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317167/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-when-perfo. Avoid passing data model directly to view, project them to viewmodel instead.